# Should I remove a closed account in my credit history?

Tags: credit-history

In my country, after a credit account (e.g. credit card, loan, mortgage) is closed, I have the option to request for this account to be removed from my credit history provided that there were no late payments more than 60 days in the last 5 years.

Is it more beneficial to keep it or remove it? Is there a threshold? In my case there is one late payment for 3~4 days, otherwise the account was good.

<sub>Note: This is not a country-specific question; I believe most credit systems in developed countries probably work the same way.</sub>